# C# EntityCode First : Unwanted foreign key created

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, ef-code-first

I have a table of "Statements" that is related to both :

- a table of "Transactions" (with a foreign key on IdStatement)
- a table of "SpecificTransactions". The class "SpecificTransaction" inherits from the table "Transaction"

This is the existing code First Model :

1. Table Statement

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [Table("Statement", Schema = "dbo")]
   public class Statement
   {
       public Statement()
       {
           this.Transactions = new List<Transaction>();
           this.SpecificTransactions = new List<SpecificTransaction>();
       }

       [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int IdStatement { get; set; }

       public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
       public List<SpecificTransaction> SpecificTransactions { get; set; }

       [... Other properties ...]
   }
   ```
2. Table Transaction

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [Table("Transaction", Schema = "dbo")]
   public class Transaction
   {
       [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int IdTransaction { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("Statement")]
       public Nullable<int> IdStatement { get; set; }

       [... Other properties ...]

   }
   ```
3. Table SpecificTransaction (inherits from Transaction)

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [Table("SpecificTransaction", Schema = "dbo")]
   public class SpecificTransaction : Transaction
   {

       [StringLength(255)]
       public string UniqueValue { get; set; }

       [StringLength(50)]
       public string Status { get; set; }

       [StringLength(50)]
       public string Hash { get; set; }

       [... Other properties ...]

   }
   ```

When the database is being created, an unwanted field (i.e column) is added on my table SpecificTransaction, called "Statement_IdStatement".

When I try to add my Statement containing SpecificTransactions, none of the following columns :

- Table Transaction > Column IdStatement
- Table SpecificTransaction > Column Statement_IdStatement

Is being populated by the IdStatement, I have to add the Id afterwards.

Furthermore, when I assign the "IdStatement" on my table "SpecificTransaction", only the "Statement_IdStatement" column is filled, and not the "IdStatement" of my table Statement.

Is there a way to :

- avoid the creation of the column "Statement_IdStatement" and keeping my EF Code First class that way ? (or at least, have no change on the tables Statement and Transaction)
- When I add my Statements containing SpecificTransactions and I saveChanges, the column "Transaction" > "IdStatement" is automatically populated ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the extra column `Statement_IdStatement` because you have declared a second relationship, directly between the `Statement` and `SpecificTransaction` model types, namely, by the property `public List<SpecificTransaction> SpecificTransactions` on your `Statement` class. This is enough to cause Entity Framework to create an extra table column to map that one-to-many relationship to, and that's why it gets filled. It doesn't need to be mapped to an extra foreign-key model property for this to occur.

You probably don't actually need that extra property on `Statement`. You can actually insert `SpecificTransaction` objects into the `Transactions` list property, and the mapping will be taken care of for you.

You may have declared this property in order to be able to access only the `SpecificTransaction` objects for your `Statement`. If this was your intent, you can alternatively access them using `myStatement.Transactions.OfType<SpecificTransaction>()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved my problem. If needed, I can post the code containing the corrections in my first post.